# Accounts.createUser and Meteor.loginWithPassword throw 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, meteor, bad-gateway, mup

I have a problem in my meteor app. My app works fine in localhost, but when I deploy it, and try to create a user with Accounts.createUser or when I try to login with Meteor.loginWithPassword, browser console prints 502 bad gateway and the app breaks. I’ve also tried calling Accounts.createUser from the server methods and still the same. The app loads database fine, I’ve tried calling other methods, and they work fine, I can insert, update and remove anything from the db inside the browser console, and the only thing that’s not working is creating a user and logging in.

I’ve tried everything that came to my mind, changing the MUP config file, the protocol, changing the server port, nginx config, server firewall, and other stuff, but nothing has worked so far. And the wierd thing, is that I have another app, that uses the same DB, is on the same server, just different port and I deploy it in the same exact way.

Meteor version is 1.8.1

MUP is used for deployment.

Server is Ubuntu 18.04, nginx hosted on DigitalOcean.

[error in browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU4r1.png)

EDIT:

mup status:

```
=> Servers
  - backdashboard.smartshopping.network: Ubuntu 18.04

=> Docker Status
 - backdashboard.smartshopping.network: 18.09.3 Running

=> Meteor Status
 - backdashboard.smartshopping.network: running 
    Created at 2019-06-17T07:49:06.464653605Z
    Restarted 2 times
    ENV: 
     - ROOT_URL=http://backdashboard.smartshopping.network
     - DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS=true
     - MONGO_URL=mongodb://Admin:password@backdashboard.smartshopping.network:27017/myDB?autoReconnect=true&connectTimeout=60000&authSource=admin
     - PORT=80
     - METEOR_SETTINGS={"public":{}}
     - PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
     - METEORD_DIR=/opt/meteord
     - NODE_VERSION=8.4.0
    Published Ports:
     - 80/tcp => 4000
    App running at http://backdashboard.smartshopping.network:80
     - Available in app's docker container: true
     - Available on server: true
     - Available on local computer: true
```

mup logs:

```
[backdashboard.smartshopping.network]=> Starting meteor app on port:80
[backdashboard.smartshopping.network]node: symbol lookup error: /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: undefined symbol: _ZN4node19GetCurrentEventLoopEPN2v87IsolateE
[backdashboard.smartshopping.network]=> Starting meteor app on port:80
[backdashboard.smartshopping.network]node: symbol lookup error: /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: undefined symbol: _ZN4node19GetCurrentEventLoopEPN2v87IsolateE
[backdashboard.smartshopping.network]=> Starting meteor app on port:80
```

Comment: Sounds like the Meteor process isn't running. What does `mup status` give you? Try `mup logs` as well and please post both as edits to your question

Comment: @Mikkel Hey Mikkel, mup logs revealed the problem. There was a problem with bcrypt, some incompability issue with Node.js, solved it with https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/656, ty very much, was stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: Haha (forgive me for laughing), it is always so simple when you find the answer :) Glad to hear you worked it out!